# Calculating multivariable limit

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{x^2y}{x^3 + y}$$

I tried the following, but im not sure if this is allowed:

Let $$t = x^3+y$$ $$(x,y)\to (0,0)$$  $$t\to 0$$ $$y=t-x^3$$
Now we will calculate the limit: $$\lim_{(x,t) \to (0,0)}x^2-\frac{x^5}{t}$$
Lets look at the path $t=x^6$ $$\lim_{(x,t) \to (0,0)}x^2-\frac{x^5}{x^6}=-\infty$$
Now lets look at the path $t=x^5$ $$\lim_{(x,t) \to (0,0)}x^2-\frac{x^5}{x^5}=-1$$
We found 2 different limits hence the limit does not exist.

Is this correct? or am I doing something wrong? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The function is not continuous at (0,0).  Another way to see this is to take the limit along $y = 0 $ and $y = x^6 - x^3$.  Your approach is correct.

Comment: I think both are $0$...

Answer (score 0):

In multivariable calculus the approach to show that a limit does not exist is exactly the approach you used. Although you used an extreme hard path, in my opinion, you could try to use some simple cases like:

$$ y = 0 $$
$$ x = 0 $$
$$ y = x^2 $$
$$ y = -x $$
$$ y = x $$

If, in these five cases, it converges to the same limit value, it *probably* - but not **necessarily** - has a well defined limit. Otherwise it doesn't have one.

As suggested by @mic, this technique only proves that a limit doesn't exist, but cannot prove that it exists. It just suggests a guess for its value. A good way to prove would be to use the delta, epsilon definition of limits.

Comment: This technique leads to a conjecture, hardly a proof.

Comment: If this shows that a limit doesn't converge to a value it doesn't have one, otherwise you could try to use more advanced techniques. It doesn't proves that a limit doesn't exist by just using those five assumptions.

Comment: I stand corrected. This technique can show whether a limit does not exist or can suggest a guess about its value (but does not prove whether such guess is correct).

Comment: What about now @mic?

Comment: Sounds better to me.